# Matplotlib circle vertices out of range

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to test each red point for inclusion with the blue circle. However, the path for my circle has some strange values which is what I believe is causing the inclusion test to not work as intended.

The axis list in the code below represent the max & min for the longitude and latitude respectively. Given that the circle is plotted at the right location I expect its path to have vertices within that range which is not the case.

Where am I going wrong?

```
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
import matplotlib.path as mpltPath

axis = [4.7469287189121001, 5.0340994897259534, 52.282706941081258, 52.432452803031282]

unitX = (axis[1]-axis[0])/10
unitY = (axis[3]-axis[2])/10

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))

for i, s in enumerate(housing_prices_shapes['2015']):
    ax.plot(s[:,0], s[:,1], linewidth=0.5, c='0.5')

circle = Ellipse(housing_prices_shapes['2015'][0][0], width=unitX, height=unitY, edgecolor='b', facecolor='None')

ax.add_patch(circle)

listings_coordinates = airbnb_prices['2015'][["longitude", "latitude"]]

path_temp = circle.get_path()
transform = circle.get_transform()

new_path = transform.transform_path(path_temp)

path = mpltPath.Path(new_path.vertices)
flag = path.contains_points(listings_coordinates)

ax.scatter(listings_coordinates['longitude'].values, listings_coordinates['latitude'].values, c='r', s=0.5)
```

Each value used to create the circle prints as follow:

```
print(housing_prices_shapes['2015'][0][0], unitX, unitY)
[  4.94147517  52.3670552 ] 0.028717077081385333 0.01497458619500236
```

The path variable which I expect to be in the same range as the longitude and latitude print as this, which is way off:

```
print(new_path.vertices)
array([[ 374.41773395,  221.41011283],
   [ 380.33706714,  221.41011283],
   [ 386.01475666,  223.12842659],
   [ 390.2003573 ,  226.18661544],
   [ 394.38595794,  229.24480429],
   [ 396.73773395,  233.39318067],
   [ 396.73773395,  237.71811283],
   [ 396.73773395,  242.04304498],
   [ 394.38595794,  246.19142136],
   [ 390.2003573 ,  249.24961022],
   [ 386.01475666,  252.30779907],
   [ 380.33706714,  254.02611283],
   [ 374.41773395,  254.02611283],
   [ 368.49840076,  254.02611283],
   [ 362.82071123,  252.30779907],
   [ 358.63511059,  249.24961022],
   [ 354.44950995,  246.19142136],
   [ 352.09773395,  242.04304498],
   [ 352.09773395,  237.71811283],
   [ 352.09773395,  233.39318067],
   [ 354.44950995,  229.24480429],
   [ 358.63511059,  226.18661544],
   [ 362.82071123,  223.12842659],
   [ 368.49840076,  221.41011283],
   [ 374.41773395,  221.41011283],
   [ 374.41773395,  221.41011283]])
```

And of course no points are flagged as `True`:

```
print(any(flag))
False
```

[image: Amsterdam]

Comment: Using `new_path = transform.transform_path(path_temp)` you transform the path to display coordinates. I suppose this is not at all desired here. Mind that you should provide a [mcve] when asking a question about undesired behaviour. Otherwise no accurate answer can be given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [ImportanceOfBeingErnest noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46792334/matplotlib-circle-vertices-out-of-range#comment80534934_46792334), you shouldn't transform your ellipse path. Well, using the untransformed path wouldn't directly be useful either; you could probably make use of `circle.get_verts()`.

But let me cut through your Gordian Knot: why not explicitly test for falling inside your ellipse? The equation of an ellipse with center `(x0,y0)` and semi-axes of length `a` and `b` is

```
(x-x0)^2/a^2 + (y-y0)^2/b^2 = 1
```

and it's really simple to see that the inside of the ellipse is then defined by the inequality

```
(x-x0)^2/a^2 + (y-y0)^2/b^2 < 1
```

(it's easy to see this for a circle, and you can think of an ellipse as a circle that went through a linear transform along one of its axes).

So use logical indexing to find which points are inside your ellipse! The only thing you need to watch out for is that the parameters passed to `Ellipse` are `2*a` and `2*b`:

```
points = airbnb_prices['2015'][['longitude', 'latitude']] # shape (N,2)
center = housing_prices_shapes['2015'][0][0] # shape (2,) broadcasts to (N,2)
a = unitX / 2 # scalar
b = unitY / 2 # scalar

# make use of broadcasting while we're at it
flag = ((points-center)**2 / np.array([a,b])**2).sum(axis=1) < 1
```

Now `flag` is a shape-`(N,)` logical array, i.e. the same shape and size as expected from your original call to `contains_points`.